# Most efficient way of purging of 10TB data from SAN?

Tags: linux, rm

I want to purge storage data from SAN which accumulates to 10 TB. The OS is linux. The storage is mounted as mount-points on a system for which it is visible I was recommended by a friend to use winscp But I don't think the tool is efficient to such an extent.

I appreciate if you can be recommended a tool or command which can help me perform this job.

Comment: rsync might be useful.

Comment: purge ? you need to Destroy it ?

Comment: I mean deletion sorry.

Comment: Only Particular ? Directory or file ?

Comment: See this Q&A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106133/why-is-rm-slow/106136#106136

Comment: entire directory?